# Асинхронный вызов функций

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Изучаю JS и NodeJS.

Когда нужно возвращать значения через колбек, а когда через return?

Рассмотрим пример:

```
function save(user, cb) {
if (!user) {
    throw new Error('user не передан');
}
if (typeof user !== 'object' || user === null) {
    throw new Error('user должен быть объектом');
}
if (!cb) {
    throw new Error('колбек не передан');
}
if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('колбек должен быть функцией');
}
validate(user, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }
    prepare(user, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        insert(user, function(err, id) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            return cb(null, id);
        });
    });
});
}
```

Эта функция сохраняет документ user в бд. Алгоритм работы:

- Проверка аргументов
- Валидация свойств аргумента user - validate
- Добавление недостающих свойств, хеширование пароля - prepare
- Вставка документа в БД.

Как видно, каждая функция получает колбек, который вызывает по окончанию своей работы. В колбеке передается ошибка, либо данные.

Вопрос: я не могу понять **когда мне нужно использовать обратный вызов, а когда можно просто возвращать значения через оператор return?**

Дополнительно пример реализации функции prepare:

```
/**
* Добавляет необходимые поля
*/
function prepare(user, cb) {
user.initials = (user.firstName[0] + user.lastName[0]).toUpperCase();
user.project = [];
user.dialogs = [];
user.locked = false;
encryptPassword(user.password, function(hashedPassword) {
    user.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
    delete user.password;
    cb(null, user);
});
}

/**
* Хеширует пароль
*/
function encryptPassword(password, cb) {
const salt = Math.random() + '';
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt).update(password).digest('hex');
cb(hashedPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллбэки нужно использовать, когда код выполняется асинхронно, не ждет выполнения какой-либо функции.

В примере `crypto.createHmac` выполняется синхронно, поэтому для `encryptPassword` и `prepare` можно использовать простой `return`.
Если бы `crypto.createHmac` выполнялся асинхронно, то коллбэк нужен был бы для него, а не для `encryptPassword`.

Код функций `validate` и `insert` вы не дали.

Вот так будет выглядеть код с return у `prepare` и `encryptPassword`:

```
function save(user, cb) {
if (!user) {
    throw new Error('user не передан');
}
if (typeof user !== 'object' || user === null) {
    throw new Error('user должен быть объектом');
}
if (!cb) {
    throw new Error('колбек не передан');
}
if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('колбек должен быть функцией');
}
validate(user, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }
    const user = prepare(user);
    insert(user, function(err, id) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        return cb(null, id);
    });
});
}
```

prepare:

```
/**
* Добавляет необходимые поля
*/
function prepare(user) {
user.initials = (user.firstName[0] + user.lastName[0]).toUpperCase();
user.project = [];
user.dialogs = [];
user.locked = false;
const hashedPassword = encryptPassword(user.password);
user.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
delete user.password;
return user;
});
}

/**
* Хеширует пароль
*/
function encryptPassword(password) {
const salt = Math.random() + '';
const hashedPassword = crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt).update(password).digest('hex');
return hashedPassword;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я начинаю сознавать, что именно не понимаю. Вы написали: - "Коллбэки нужно использовать, когда код выполняется асинхронно, не ждет выполнения какой-либо функции." Как определить, что код выполняется асинхронно? Мой ответ: Существует ряд операций которые могут выполняться ТОЛЬКО асинхронно, например: обращение к БД, чтение с диска, работа с сетью и т.п.(их можно охарактеризовать так - "придется ожидать ответа, ничего не делая"). Когда имеем дело с такими операциями, то нужно использовать колбеки.

Comment: @ПавелЗубков Если для этого вы используете какую-то библиотеку, то смотрите в документации. Как правило, асинхронные функции либо принимают коллбэк в аргументах, либо возвращают [промис](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise). Например, [fs.WriteFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) принимает функцию как аргумент. Кроме того, можно использовать аналогичную функцию [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options), но процесс "зависнет" во время ее выполнения.